# Create And populate a TemP Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table with a field that holds a sequence of numbers for each of four different entity's, Field szDocumentNrLocal holds the numbers Field gbaEntityIdFk holds the identity of the entity's. I am attempting to create a temp table with one field (ID) and then to populate the table with the sequence of numbers for a specific entity in order that I may then work with the resulting table to obtain missing numbers in the sequences. My sql looks like the following:

> declare @EntityId int; select @EntityId =1 IF
>   OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#sequence') IS NOT NULL  BEGIN
>       DROP TABLE #sequence END   create table #sequence (id int not null primary key) INSERT INTO #sequence (id) VALUES((select
>   Cast([szDocumentNrLocal] as int) from dbo.tms_Document_ex where
>   EntityIdFk = @EntityId))

The code is producing the error: Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 14
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
The statement has been terminated.

How do I do this properly please?

Comment: Don't use `VALUES`. Simply do `INSERT INTO #sequence SELECT...`.

Comment: Thanks Larnu thats exactly what I wanted.